# Are these values dependencies?

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

I've got an object that encapsulates remote calls. It needs credentials to make the calls. I think the credentials should be passed into the constructor so that, once the object is created, a user doesn't have to keep passing them in every time they make a call to the object. This seems like a sensible factoring.

If I do this though I've got the added complexity of the clients that use this object needing to be passed a factory instead of the object itself because they credentials won't be known until run time. So given this extra work, I was wondering if credentials (being just string values and no code) count as a dependency or not?

Does this question even make sense? You see I've gotten it into my head after using IoC that anything being passed into a constructor counts as a dependency and thus should probably be an instance of some implementation of an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't see those strings as dependencies. Instead, create an `IUserContext` or `IUserCredentials` abstraction that you can inject.

Comment: Well actually I'm using a Credentials class to keep the number of parameters down. ;) But I'm not convinced... just wrapping some string values in a container doesn't change the fact that the object being instantiated requires data to be passed into the constructor as opposed to code implementations. So if you think its OK to add in a 'IUserContext' then I think its OK to pass in raw strings.

Comment: I suppose that wrapping in strings in a container does make it much more clear what the values are for when using factories that described like, for example, this... Func<Credentials, IService>.

Comment: Strings are not dependencies, they are configuration. It is usually fine to inject configuration values using constructor injection, but I try to prevent mixing dependencies with configuration values in a single constructor. An `IUserContext` can get very useful when the use information is 'context' specific. Think about having a user per thread (such as ASP.NET does).

Comment: "I try to prevent mixing dependencies with configuration values in a single constructor." So how do you do that?

Comment: By extracting those configuration values into their own class, or by using Properties for those configuration values.

Comment: But how does extracting those configuration values into their own class stop an instance of that class from just being a different type of configuration value?

Comment: When you simply wrap those values in a class return them throw public properties, in that case there is no use. But if you can, abstract away those values and supply useful methods on that abstraction, such as `LogOn()`. But don't forget user name and password are not configuration values, since they might differ per thread.

Comment: I don't see how those values can be hidden in my case. The calling code is iterating over a list of accounts and each account has a different set of config values to be passed to the factory which creates the object that does the remote calls.

Comment: "But don't forget user name and password are not configuration values, since they might differ per thread.". Then "Strings are not dependencies, they are configuration." isn't always true.

Comment: A dependency is a service that that abstracts away a part of the system. A string can never be an abstraction, thus never be a dependency (in DI terminology).

Comment: "A string can never be an abstraction". A string *is* an abstraction. It abstracts away a particular string value in the same way that an ILogin interface abstracts away a particular implementation of logging in.

Comment: String doesn't abstract away the value. It *is* the value.

Comment: A string instance is a value. String is the type. Just as ILogin is the type and 'Login' is the value (for the code at least). ;)

Comment: In Dependency Injection, our dependencies are services that have (business) logic. When we inject a string, we don't consider this a dependency, but simply a configuration value.

Comment: ok, well fair enough. I understand that's the convention but I'm not convinced that this constraint needs to be there. Whether its config or business logic, one might typically want it going in through the constructor and hence passed in by the IoC container.